# Differentiability of $L^p$ norm

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives

Let $2 < p < \infty$ and $f, g \in L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \nu)$ be fixed elements of norm $1$, where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \nu)$ is any measure space. Consider the function $F$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$F(t) = \int_{\Omega}|f+t\,g|^{p} d\nu.$$
Is $F$ twice continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. is $F$ of class $C^2$? Theorem 2.6 in Analysis by Lieb and Loss asserts that $F$ is differentiable at $t=0$, but I wanted to know if this holds for all $t$ and if any higher derivatives exist and are continuous. I know that $x \mapsto  |x|^p$ is $n = \left\lfloor{p}\right\rfloor  - 1$ times differentiable, but does not have a continuous $n$th derivative, so my guess is that the same holds here; $F$ is also $n$-times differentiable or $n-1$-times continuously differentiable. Do any additional assumptions on the measure space allow us to infer any more differentiability class properties of $F$?

Comment: You need to make sure that integral that represents $F'''$ etc. remains defined.

Comment: @UmbertoP. is that sufficient?